# OAuthException 101 in rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I get this error in my app

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}
```

what I've done:
- I have a config/initializers/omniauth.rb file containing:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['my App ID:'], ENV['my app Secret']
end
```

- I have a view containing 
  link_to "Log in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook"

My app is not embeded in facebook and this error happens in my online app (not localhost)
Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'fbgraph'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'less-rails'
group :assets do
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
   gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing ENV[]:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'my App ID:', 'my app Secret'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing ENV[ ] and restarting rails server solved my problem.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'my App ID:', 'my app Secret'
end
```

More info on RailsCasts tutorial: http://goo.gl/yrj6c

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to change your Site URL for your webapp on Facebook Development from localhost to your domain name?

Comment: Check your validations and make sure your auth hash is correct when you're assigning it. I had this same problem and it turned out that Facebook name could not be saved into my user's name because of my formatting validation. Check out the Auth Hash table here: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Comment: I finally gave up and used Koala from all the process and it's working fine now

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the app wasn't able to get the api key and secret. now I'm getting a

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError (OAuthException: Error validating verification code.) while doing this:
        @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new('app key', 'app secret', 'http://mywebsite.com/facebook/callback')

    @oauth.url_for_oauth_code
    @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code])
```

and it happens after the user accepted to login via facebook

Answer (score 0):

OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'my App ID:', 'my app Secret'
end

AND....take off ENV[],

ALSO dont forget to restart your server every time that you update the file. :)